# ASP.net loading just data onload instead of page HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am having some issues with just wanting to output some data to the page without having all the HTML load. I am using AJAX to call the same ASPX page in order to populate some data to be returned to the AJAX call. However, it currently **does call** and it **does populate with the correct data** *BUT* it does not seem to want to place that data onto the page.

It currently has an error loading the page of *"This webpage is not available: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"*

When I load the page like so:

```
http://localhost:2765/Default.aspx?Data=viewData
```

is where I receive the error of *"This webpage is not available: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"*. Placing some code breaks in, I can confirm that it does populated the needed data but never seems to display it on the page and it also seems to call the page at least 2 times before finally stopping (possibly causing the error above).

The default.aspx code is this:

```
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="AdminPanel._default" %>
 <% If loadHTMLPage Then %>
   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     ....[more HTML code here]....
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var clickedButtonName = "";

        $('#dashboardData, #viewData, #updateData, #addData, #deleteData').click(function() {
            clickedButtonName = '#' + $(this).attr("id");

            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("id") + ".aspx",
                dataType: 'html',
                timeout: 10000,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#jQueryLoadHere").html(html);
                    $('#dashName').html("<strong>" + $(clickedButtonName).data("title") + "</strong> Page");
                    $('#dashboardData_LI, #viewData_LI, #updateData_LI, #addData_LI, #deleteData_LI').attr('class', 'nav-parent');
                    $(clickedButtonName + '_LI').attr('class', 'nav-parent nav-active active');
                }
            });
        });
     });
     </script>
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
 <% Else %>
 <% =pageData %>
 <% End If %>
```

The codebehind is this:

```
Public Class _default
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
   Dim whatData As String = Nothing
   Public loadHTMLPage As Boolean = True

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    whatData = Request.QueryString("Data")

    Response.Write(whatData)

    If whatData = "viewData" And hasLoaded = False Then
        loadHTMLPage = False
        hasLoaded = True
        Call workingGetFEBList()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub workingGetFEBList()
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(apiURL & appID & "/" & formID & "?format=text/xml")

    request.Method = "GET"
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Dim response1 As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response1.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim serverResponse As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    Response.Close()

    Dim theOutput As String = parseXML2JSON(serverResponse)

    pageData = theOutput
End Sub
```

If I comment out:

```
Call workingGetFEBList()
pageData = theOutput
```

and refresh the page - it works just fine loading the page (blank white page with just **viewData** text on it).

Likewise, just loading the page:

```
http://localhost:2765/Default.aspx
```

Loads up the page with the normal HTML just fine.

So what could I be missing??

Comment: Response.Close(). Stops all response from the server. Means event will run on the server but response will not come to the client

Comment: @SainPradeep well crap, that Response.Close() should be response1.Close(). After changing that it works just fine... figures. Please place your reply as the "official" answer, please so i can give you credit!